# How to change height of iframe from px to percentile

Tags: iframe

I am working on WCAG 2.0 ,one of the requirement says **Use relative rather than absolute units in HTML attributes. Use percentages rather than pixels for sizing frames and tables**.

The actual problem is with iframe controls. When ichange the width its fine , but the height is not changing when it changed from px to %.

The content of iframe is cross domain.

```
<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
         <iframe id="led_frame" width="1000" height="900" frameborder="no" title="Employment  Dynamics" src="http://lehd.did.census.gov/led/index.html" name="led_frame" style="margin- left:-35px">
    ..............
    </iframe>
</div>
```

i tried
 1. adding height to container div.
 2. adding height to body tag.

Any suggestion will be helpful..............

Comment: add a `style="width: 100%; height: 90%;"` attribute

Comment: i already tried it....the height became small and not change ..

Comment: did you try  `min-height: 100%`?